# nested Ternary condition in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor, conditional-operator

I Have a ternary Condition like below in HTML template file,

```
<div
*ngFor="let $m of $layer.child; let $childIndex=index"
[Latitude]="$m.latitude"
[Longitude]="$m.longitude"
[IconInfo]="$childIndex== 0 ? _iconInfo1:$childIndex== 1 ? _iconInfo 
:$childIndex== 2 ? _iconInfo2:$childIndex== 3 ? 
_trunkLocMarker1:_trunkLocMarker"></div>
```

In the same condition i want to change a value of particular property in IconInfo Like below:

```
if($m.propertyValue > 1000){
  _iconInfo1.property = 'someValue';
}
```

In the same Ternary condition.

I tried some thing like below:

```
 [IconInfo] = "$childIndex== 0 ? _iconInfo1:$childIndex== 1 ? _iconInfo :$childIndex == 2 ? _iconInfo2 : ($m.totalMou > '1000' ?_iconInfo2.fontSize = '48' : _iconInfo2.fontSize = '48'): $childIndex == 3 ? _trunkLocMarker1 : _trunkLocMarker "
```

But I get error saying that:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments
```

Please help!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You cannot assign values in template expressions. Perhaps your requirement could be achieved in some other way. Could you please show how/where the `_iconInfo2.fontSize` property is used?

Comment: I think you should put your split your ternary into smaller statements and put them in functions that you'll call in your template

Comment: @JoH: Calling function in data binding isn't a good idea if the change detection isn't handled manually. The function will be triggered multiple times.

Comment: What's going on with the div having input properties? 
If this is for a component you have created with these input properties it would be easiest to pass in the property to the component and filter there (ngOnInit or ngOnChanges, depending on if the properties are updating at runtime)

Comment: Formatting is very important. I don't see any mistakes, but it takes way too long to read when you don't format properly

Comment: re-thinking your code, it's better calculate the _iconInfo.property using a forEach in the **.ts**

Answer (score 0):

The error says you can't have assignments.  You have two of them (singe = is assignment)

```
$m.totalMou > '1000' ?_iconInfo2.fontSize = '48' : _iconInfo2.fontSize = '48'
```

NOTE: I don't really recommend having so many nested ternary conditions, especially in the template.  They are hard to follow.  You should move that logic to the typescript.